# Empty row in grid view

Tags: c#-3.0

How to add an empty row in the grid view at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Insert at index 0 in your datasource.

e.g.

```
DataRow newRow;
newRow = dataSet.dataTable.NewRow();
newRow[0] = "a";
newRow[1] = "b";
// ...

dataSet.dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(myNewRow, 0);
```

Comment: is it possible to do it in this way as i dont get it??